# What is the point of refs in Extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am still trying to understand what the point of [refs](http://training.figleaf.com/tutorials/senchacomplete/chapter2/lesson5/3.cfm) are in Extjs. There seems to be an enormous lack of documentation on the subject.

Refs are supposed to make life easier but I have found that the opposite is true, and I am wondering if it is because I am not using them to their full potential.

If I were to use a ref for a combo in my controller I might have some code like this :

```
refs: [{
    ref: 'maritalStatusCombo',
    selector: 'combo[name="maritalstatus"]',
}]

myFunction: function () {
    var comp = this.getMaritalStatusCombo();
}
```

However I could just as easily write code like this :

```
var maritalStatusComboSelector = 'combo[name="maritalstatus"]'

myFunction: function () {
    var comp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(maritalStatusComboSelector)
}
```

This second version uses less text (..i think), and is more clear to understand IMO.

Also my IDE understands the second much better.

If I select *'navigate to..'* on the selector string it takes me straight to the declaration up the top. In the first example *'navigate to..'* on the **getMaritalStatusCombo()** function doesn't take me anywhere.

How are refs supposed to make life easier?

Comment: They have some merit in Ext4 for avoiding duplication / having the selectors specified several times - but it's worth noting that `refs` do not exist on `ViewControllers` in Ext5 and above - they use a different kind of references (and regular controllers tend to end up not being used for "view" related stuff).  The point being, there's no real advantage in adopting `refs` as far as upgrading the framework is concerned - so if they don't work for you, there's no harm in ignoring them.

Answer (score 4):

The refs config creates a getter method on the controller that internally uses Ext.ComponentQuery to fetch the component instance using the configured selector. The following example will add the getList method to the controller and will return the first component in the application hierarchy with an xtype of "grid". By default, undefined will be returned when the query does not locate the target component.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Foo', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [{
        ref: 'list',
        selector: 'grid'
    }]
});
```

So simply you can create a getter method on the first element with 'selector' xtype. I use it a lot with forms, for example, on my login controller i can get my form simply using a getForm.

Obviously you can create your own method like you told us, but using refs is exactly the same, and you can create lots of them using the refs prop array without creating lots of getters for every single component needed.

Simply I got that is a simple way to have getters all in one place.